# How to initialize a multibody force object for CalcForceElementsContribution()?

Tags: drake

I want to calculate the manipulator equation for my plant context. I have a linearspringdamper, so I tried to use CalcForceElementsContribution() to get tau_app.

[CalcForceElementsContribution()](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#ae1b54c8562f107e4d6e11b4b0f8d53c5) requires a [MultibodyForces](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_forces.html#aeff2b3798b49185928b79d66fb66afdc) force object as an input, but it seems MultibodyForces can only be applied to a MultibodyTreeSystem? I have been using MultibodyPlant, so I am not sure where to go from here. Here is the code so far:

```
plant.SetPositions(plant_context, q_pos)
plant.SetVelocities(plant_context, q_vel)

M = plant.CalcMassMatrixViaInverseDynamics(plant_context)
Cv = plant.CalcBiasTerm(plant_context)
tauG = plant.CalcGravityGeneralizedForces(plant_context)

leg_frame = plant.GetBodyByName("stance_leg").body_frame()
ground_frame = plant.GetBodyByName("ground").body_frame()

# Jacobian of the stance foot
J = plant.CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity(
    plant_context,
    JacobianWrtVariable(0),
    leg_frame,
    foot_in_leg["stance_leg"],
    ground_frame,
    ground_frame,
)

# discard y components since we are in 2D
J = J[[0, 2]]

tau_app = ???   #multibody forces
plant.CalcForceElementsContribution(plant_context, tau_app)

m_eq = M.dot(qdd) + Cv - tauG - J.T.dot(f) - tau_app
```

This problem is related to [#13476](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13476), but I am not sure if the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* [this](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/underactuated/multibody.py) is what you're looking for?

```
def ManipulatorDynamics(plant, q, v=None, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()
    plant.SetPositions(context, q)
    if v is not None:
        plant.SetVelocities(context, v)
    M = plant.CalcMassMatrixViaInverseDynamics(context)
    Cv = plant.CalcBiasTerm(context)
    tauG = plant.CalcGravityGeneralizedForces(context)
    B = plant.MakeActuationMatrix()
    forces = MultibodyForces_(plant)
    plant.CalcForceElementsContribution(context, forces)
    # TODO(russt): add in contact forces to tauExt.
    tauExt = plant.CalcGeneralizedForces(context, forces)

    return (M, Cv, tauG, B, tauExt)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was stuck on! Once I got CalcForceElementsContribution working, however, I have that tauExt is a zero vector despite the fact that the linear spring damper was compressed for the given context. Maybe I am still missing something?

Comment: That seems suspicious.  Can you provide a reproduction?

Comment: Do you mean LinearSpringDamper? In that case forces will be added into forces.body_forces(). MultibodyForces lumps together both generalized forces and spatial forces. So if you are using the LinearSpringDamper I would expect that borces.generalized_forces() will be zero.

Comment: I gave it a try but got: "MultibodyForces has no attribute 'body_forces'". I couldn't find a way to access the body forces in the documentation. Here is the link to the Deepnote notebook (https://deepnote.com/workspace/jasmines-workspace-f70d-1bc8a875-c2ab-4df9-a8bc-ebe405a350f7/project/swing-spring-815-Duplicate2-Duplicate-d99f605f-e8f2-45e1-ab12-aa1841828bf0/notebook/cartpoles_urdf-a9f551f4051b404eaeea7d4aef0bf96e).

Comment: I discussed with Alejandro today, and have updated my answer above... using MultibodyPlant::CalcGeneralizedForce to get the effects of both generalized forces and body spatial forces. That method was not bound in python yet, but I've opened: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/20102 (it should land very soon)

Comment: I have found that when the spring has zero deflection, the force I obtain from CalcGeneralizedForces does not match CalcGravityGeneralizedForces. I would have guessed that these two functions would report the same force vector at this configuration. Could this be an issue with how I've set up the model?